# Count of number of times a max of the dates in two columns is bigger than the date in the third column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, countif

I have three columns in a report: a closure date (Col A), an implementation date (Col B) and a target date (Col C).

I need to count the number of times an entry is closed or implemented before the target date, during the course of a month. Due to a system limitation in some cases there is both a closed date and an implementation date for a single entry. Therefore my COUNTIFS formula is counting these instances twice:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"<="&C:C,A:A,">="&DATE(2019,1,1),A:A,"<"&DATE(2019,2,1))+COUNTIFS(B:B,"<="&C:C,B:B,">="&DATE(2019,1,1),B:B,"<"&DATE(2019,2,1))
```

In these cases I need to compare the latest (maximum) of the two dates against the target date.

Does anyone know of a formula that could help?

Comment: I'm surprised that the criteria `"<="&C:C` works. If excel interprets that range as an array then you need to wrap the `COUNTIFS` with `SUM`. But even then, I don't believe it is doing a pairwise comparison that I believe you are asking for. I think you need a helper column, or an array formula

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `SUMPRODUCT`.  I try to avoid whole-column references with array-formulas and, if you have column headers in row 1, then you MUST exclude row 1 from your calculations.  (Or use a Table with structured references).

So a formula that will give you a count of when your TARGET date is greater than  both of your Closure/Implementation dates (which is another way of saying that the latest of Closure/Implementation occurred before TARGET)

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C1000>A2:A1000)*(C2:C1000>B2:B1000))
```

If you want to check for only a particular month, then expand the formula to include the "date test":  (eg, for January)

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C1000>A2:A1000)*(C2:C1000>B2:B1000)*(C2:C1000>=DATE(2019,1,1))*(C2:C1000<DATE(2019,2,1)))
```